# Why export-ignore files are included in vendor folder while using 'dist' in Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a standard Laravel 10x project with standard `composer.json` from Laravel installer with the following settings:

```
"config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "discard-changes": true,
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
```

But in (let's say vendor->laravel->framework) I still see `/test` in the Vendor dir. Although I can clearly see that it includes `.gitattributes` file  with `/tests export-ignore`

I have even tried to do `composer update --prefer-dist` with no luck.